# Deleting multiple MySQL records from a hyperlink with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am trying to delete multiple records using check boxes. I've loaded each check box with the record ID:

```
<?php $row_count = 1; do {  ?>
    <tr <?php if ($row_count%2) { ?>bgcolor="#F4F4F4"<?php } ?>>
      <td align="center" ><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="<?php echo $row_contactlist['contact_id']; ?>"></td>
      <td align="center" ><p><?php echo $row_contactlist['contact_id'];?></p></td>
    </tr>
    <?php $row_count++; } while ($row_contactlist = mysql_fetch_assoc($contactlist)); ?>
```

I'm running the delete using the following link:

```
<a class="addcontact" href="delete.php?mContact=<?php for($i=0;$i<=$row_count;$i++) { $del_id = $checkbox[$i]; } echo $del_id ?>" style="border-bottom:0px" >Delete Contact(s)</a>
```

that runs delete.php

```
if (isset($_GET['mContact'])) {
mysql_query("DELETE FROM contacts WHERE contact_id = ".$_GET['mContact']."");
mysql_query("DELETE FROM history WHERE history_contact = ".$_GET['mContact']."");
mysql_query("DELETE FROM notes WHERE note_contact = ".$_GET['mContact']."");
redirect('You have deleted some contacts',"contacts.php");
}
```

The redirect works i.e. the contacts page reloads with 'you have deleted some contacts' and it looks like I get no errors, but none of the contacts are deleted.

**UPDATE:**
Thanks guys very speedy response. Total newb to PHP so everything is massively appreciated.

So I'll use a sumbit button not a hyperlink:

```
<td colspan="5" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" value="Delete"></td>
```

Comment: oh man! You are going to get so _many_ validation complaints!

Comment: id of checkboxes should not be the same.

Comment: Hopefully nothing ever spiders your site, or you're going to nice empty database next time you look.

Comment: where are you checking the checkbox[] array to see whats checked?

Comment: Try this link [http://localhost/contacts.php?mContact=1%3Bdrop%20table%20contacts](http://localhost/contacts.php?mContact=1%3Bdrop%20table%20contacts) ;) For more background information, read [SQL injection attacks by example](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html).

Comment: @Gaurav I believe the checkboxes can have the same id, it just doesn't validate as proper HTML but it won't affect the processing of the form in PHP.

Comment: @Patrick Unique IDs do have functional impact on client-side JavaScript though. It's important that they be different.

Comment: @meager Yes, I totally agree but the OP isn't using any Javascript

Comment: How is it best to label the checkBoxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're having a mixup dealing with the selection of the criteria to be deleted.

The link that takes the user to the delete page has nothing to do with the checkboxes in the code.

I believe what you want to do is

1. Create the checkboxes (and if you want something to be deleted by default, set `checked="checked"`
2. Change the `<a href..>` to a submit button
3. In the `delete.php` the checkboxes will be in an array `$_GET['checkboxes']`, which you can iterate through

NOW, onto the issues that @JohnP alluded to:

1. This is pretty insecure way to do this unless you have removed all your validation code before posting here.
2. I would recommend passing everything by `$_POST` for a little bit more security through obscurity
3. Check that the user has the privileges to delete the rows that they are attempting to delete.
4. Set a `LIMIT 1` on each delete (or update) query so you don't accidentally delete all the rows in your database.

**UPDATE**

If you want to have a single delete link, you would need to add the link inside the `do...while` loop.  It appears that you have the link outside that loop and you loop through every result and add them all to the `mContact` token.  As a single, long string of numbers, your handling script does not have a way of parsing that information without delimiters.

Comment: Thanks patrick for your reply. I'll try and get my head around $_POST, and the iteration of the do.. while

Answer (score 0):

Instead of redirecting right away, comment out your redirect function and allow it to stay on the page after completing the `mysql_query()` calls.  Do you see any errors reported there (if `display_errors = on` in php.ini)  Does your error log report errors?

Also, and surely I won't be the only one to say... You MUST validate `$_GET['mContact']` before passing it to `mysql_query`.  This is highly vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks.  You must check that it is an integer, or whatever data type your record `contact_id` is.

Further, it is unwise to use a hyperlink to delete records from the database without a confirmation page in between.  Will this page ever be crawled by an indexer?  The indexer will hit the delete links and cause deletion.  The preferred method is to use a form with a submit button for deletion.

Comment: Nothing is passed to mContact i.e. delete.php is empty

Comment: I think I've got a lot to think about. Thanks for the validation tip.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not putting foreign keys on `history_contact` and `note_contact` referencing `contact_id` with `CASCADE DELETE`?

That way if you delete a contact, MySQL will take care of deleting the children for you..

(As previous posts suggest, validate your data input against SQL injections!)

Comment: Good advice. I think this is also on my to list. Thanks for your help